# systemverilog: difference between declaring class handle inside module and outside module

Tags: system-verilog

i want to understand the difference between creating class handle outside and inside module. I have 3 cases and i want to understand the significance of each

**case 1:**

```
class abc;
...
..
endclass

abc obj1; //declaration outside module

 module xyz();

    initial

      obj1=new; //creating object

 endmodule
```

**case 2:**

```
   class abc;
   ...
   ..
   endclass


   module xyz();

   abc obj1; //declaration inside module

      initial

         obj1=new; //creating object

    endmodule
```

**case 3**

```
    class abc;
    ...
    ..
    endclass

    module xyz();

       initial

         abc obj1=new; //declaring and creating object

    endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope outside a module is called a *compilation unit* and referred to as `$unit`. At a minimum, it includes all the space outside a module within a single text file. At a maximum, it can include all the text outside a module in a single compilation step. There is no way to share definitions across separate compilation units. Class definitions are typically put in a `package` so they can be shared across different units.

Also note [the difference between a class *handle* and a class *variable*](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/07/16/class-on-classes/). A variable belongs to a particular scope, but a handle does not. A handle is just a value that gets assigned to a variable and that value can be passed between scopes.

The significant difference between **case1** and **case2** is when there are multiple instances of `module xyz` **case2** creates a unique `obj1` variable and concurrent `initial` block for each instance of the module that constructs as many objects as there are instances.  **case1** also has the concurrent `initial` blocks, but only one `obj1` variable in `$unit`. So although both cases construct the same number of object handles, There is only one variable to hold one handle. Which one it chooses is a race condition.

**case3** is almost the same as **case2**, but is ***illegal*** according to the LRM. You are not allowed to have a declaration initialization on implicitly static variable that could have been declared with an explicit automatic lifetime. This is because of legacy Verilog's choice of making all declarations having a static lifetime by default, whereas most other programming languages default to having an automatic lifetime. The problem shows up best when the declaration initialization is inside a looping construct.

To fix this you would have to write

```
initial
   static abc obj1=new; //declaring and creating object
```

or

```
initial being
  abc obj1; //declaring and
  obj1=new; // creating object
end
```